# How to close jetty Http Connection after the web service method is executed

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, request, jetty, httpconnection

While configuring embedded jetty server in jetty 9.3.8, I am adding a connection listener to the server connector for keeping track of opening and closing of jetty HttpConnection.

The jetty thread [qtp..........] that is serving current request opens up a HttpConnection. After finishing the current request, how do i inform the jetty to close this HttpConnection. I do see closing of all opened connections in the callback from the listener from different clients after some time of serving the request.

I need to close the connection once i finish with the request, that is when i am done with a particular client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing of the connection is the responsibility of the HTTP spec and protocol.

> Note: Be aware that connection close is HTTP version specific, following different semantics for HTTP/1.0 vs HTTP/1.1 vs HTTP/2

In general, the connection open/close handling is negotiated between the HTTP client and the HTTP server, and needs to follow those rules.  Having the server arbitrarily close the connection based on some non HTTP spec behavior is ripe for abuse and will cause problems with intermediaries (such as proxies, routers, load balancers, caching servers, etc).

Comment: HTTP/1.1 is used in this case. If i just interrupt the thread on which the request is being processed, i see the HttpConnection close happen as expected.  But when jetty allocates the same thread [qtp..........] for some other request, i see a http connection close and on the http client i get the 'no http response'. How can i just clear the thread's interrupt flag and other data between requests?

Comment: You should not be messing around with that part of the processing of a Connection and Request.  Also, interrupting any thread in a Servlet container is 100% not supported by the Servlet spec (and JEE) and guaranteed to cause you problems.

Comment: I am upgrading from 9.2.8 to 9.3.8, Initially in the previous version, we use to interrupt the jetty thread after the request is done(in case of long lived heart beat threads), which helped us to close the low level Jetty Http Connections. But after removing the interrupt on this output thread, the system is not giving the expected performance. Anything els e that can help me on this.

Comment: 9.2 to 9.3 was a giant leap in connection and request handling as 9.3 added support for HTTP/2.

Comment: First, do **not** interrupt threads managed by Jetty, that's a recipe for disaster (its against the servlet spec, against the jetty internals, ang against the recommendations of Java itself!).  All connection closes should be part of the negotiated HTTP protocol, use the HTTP specs to handle that appropriately.  Next, know that arbitrary closing the various streams associated with the HttpServletRequest and/or HttpServletResponse is usually enough to indicate that the connection is no longer needed.  Lastly, upgrade to Jetty 9.3.10.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this header in the request: Connection: close